# ARC doesn't apply to struct and enum, how are they deallocated in Swift

Tags: swift, memory-management, structure, automatic-ref-counting, value-type

Since ARC doesn't apply to struct and enum, then how are they deallocated from the memory? I have to get stuck when it asked in the interviews and try to find the correct answer but can't find much info on it googling. I know swift is smart at handling value types. But how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The memory management of objects (instances of classes) is relatively difficult, because objects can outlive a function call, the life of other objects, or even the life of the threads that allocated them. They're independent entities on the heap, that need book keeping to make sure they're freed once they're not needed (once they're no longer referenced from any other threads/objects, they're unreachable, thus *can't possible be needed*, so are safe to delete).

On the other hand, structs and enums just have their instances stored inline:

- If they're declared as a global variable, they're stored in the program text.
- If they're declared as a local variable, they're allocated on the stack (or in registers, but never mind that).
- If they're allocated as a property of another object, they're just
  stored directly inline within that object.

They're only ever deleted
by virtue of their containing context being deallocated, such as when
a function returns, or when an object is deallocated.

Comment: That's almost true, except that several structs have value semantics (Array, Dictionary, Set, String) and are actually implemented as references.  Likewise you can have an indirect enum and also a reference as an associated value and in all of these cases the object must be released from the heap and its deinit must be called.

Comment: @JoshHomann "except that several structs have value semantics (Array, Dictionary, Set, String) and are actually implemented as references." I'm not sure how that's relevant here. Structs and enums with associated values can contain objects, and those objects work just the same as any other objects, so I don't see a point to mentioning that. "Likewise you can have an indirect enum" Ah yes, I forgot to mention those.

Comment: Its relevant because the question states "ARC doesn't apply to struct and enum" which on the surface might seem like its true, but when you look at the implementation its actually not true; all of the cases that I mentioned either directly or indirectly involve reference counted ARC objects in the heap that are obfuscated by the wrapping value type.

Comment: @JoshHomann Ah, I see. So I would phrase it "ARC applies to structs/enums, in-so-far as it applies to the class instances stored within those structs/enums"... plus `indirect`.

Comment: @Alexander If locally allocated struct values are deallocated when a function returns, then how a return of struct type works?   In C it gives warning if we are trying to return a locally allocated value from a function!!

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB it’s just copied out, like in C. The only issue would be if you try to return a pointer to a local variable, which will become a dangling pointer after returning.